# Can't print nested list in an XML from an API

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

This is the results of an API request (truncated for space and focus)

```
{
  "bib": [
    {
      "mms_id": "################",
      "record_format": "marc21",
      "network_number": [
        "(OCoLC)########",
        "(OCoLC)########",
        "(OCoLC)########"
      ],
      "place_of_publication": "Boston :",
      "holdings": {
        "link": "https://api-na.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/almaws/v1/bibs/#############/holdings"
      },
      "created_by": "System",
      "created_date": "2021-02-03Z",
      "cataloging_level": {
        "value": "00",
        "desc": "Default Level"
      },
      "brief_level": {
        "value": "10",
        "desc": "10"
      },
      "anies": [
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><record><leader>04746cam  2200697 i 4500</leader><controlfield ">1</subfield></datafield></record>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total_record_count": 1
}
```

I am trying to access the data in the anies field but the best I've managed is an empty list. I have tried several different methods to the info but none work. Note, the actual anies field is over 10,000 characters in a single string.

This mirrors what I use to pull info from most of the fields like mms_id

```
    for anies in root.findall('bib/anies'):
        print(anies.text)
```

These were attempts to mirror what I use to get holdings/link

```
    for child in root.findall('.//anies'):
        print(child)
    for num in root.findall('.//anies/'):
        b = num.attrib
           print(b)
```

This one mirrors what I use to pull the info from network_number, which most closely resembles the anies field and this is the one that gives me an empty list as a result.

```
e = root.findall('.//anies')
print(e)
```

Additionally, it's worth mentioning I don't actually need to print the anies field but I need to look for certain text within the string. I just use print to quickly check if it is working.

I hope this was clear enough.

Comment: The result of the API call is not XML, it's dictionaries and lists. You need to parse the XML in `result['bib'][0]['anies'][0]`

Comment: can't you do smth like
Access the "bib" field, which is a list.
Retrieve the first element of the "bib" list.
Access the "anies" field within the first element.
``data = json.loads(response)
anies_data = data["bib"][0]["anies"][0]``

Comment: The contained xml is not a valid xml. This string have several failures.

Comment: it looks like it should be JSON, like @xFranko said, but running `json.loads` on it returns an error. It looks like there is something wrong with it

Comment: are you sure this is xml input? it looks like json?